# grouping by week mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, grouping

i have this sql which selects data from the database and returns two columns

for this sql,

```
SELECT count(*) cnt, date(created) dt FROM mlm_users GROUP by dt
```

i get something line

```
count, date
1, 2013-05-10
2, 2013-06-10
11, 2013-09-10
```

for the following,

```
SELECT count(*) cnt, week(DATE_SUB(created, INTERVAL 1 DAY)) dt 
FROM mlm_users GROUP by dt
```

i get

count, week no

```
1, 12
2, 22
11, 34
```

is there anyway i can return the week date range like

count, week no

```
 1, 2013-01-12 - 2013-07-12 
 2,  2013-08-12 - 2013-14-12 
 11,  2013-15-12 - 2013-29-12
```

and for the mnonth return thw month

```
SELECT month( created ) dt, date(created) dt FROM mlm_users GROUP by dt
```

i could have calculated this value manually, but because of minor issues in date calculation, i wanted to know if the database can give this value.

pls see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cd3db/2

thanks

Comment: put some sample data on http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: Do you have 2 date columns in your table?What is the criteria for this range for example 2013-01-12 - 2013-07-12 ?

Comment: the `created` is a date column, there is no criteria, the result returns the week numbers, i was hoping i could get the start date and end date from the week number

Comment: @raheelshan pls see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cd3db/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this,if I understand you

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cd3db/18

Comment: yes, that was for the day, i was talking of the second query, for the week select, check http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cd3db/20